# Webclient not working when threading (VB 2013)

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

So here's my program flow:

```
Public Function previewAssigner()
    Dim pt1 As Thread

    pt1 = New Thread(AddressOf pt)

    pt1.Start()
End Function
Private Sub pt()
    MsgBox("PT")

    Dim tClient As WebClient = New WebClient

    Dim tImage As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromStream(New MemoryStream(tClient.DownloadData(apicurl)))

    FormDisplay.PictureBox1.Image = tImage
End Sub
```

Messagebox appears saying PT just fine, but image does not load. But if I paste the code in pt() to the function, it works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit fiddly to access a control from a different thread: see [How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you wanted a method to set an arbitrary PictureBox to an image from an arbitrary URL, you could do something like this:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Delegate Sub SetImageCallback(target As PictureBox, bmp As Bitmap)

    Friend Class ImageLoaderParameters
        Property Target As PictureBox
        Property URL As Uri
    End Class

    Sub LoadImageFromUrl(target As PictureBox, url As Uri)
        Dim ilp As New ImageLoaderParameters With {.Target = target, .URL = url}
        Dim t1 As New Thread(AddressOf LoadImageFromUrlHelper)
        t1.Start(ilp)

    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadImageFromUrlHelper(args As Object)
        Dim ilp = DirectCast(args, ImageLoaderParameters)
        Using wc As New WebClient
            Dim tImage As Bitmap = CType(Bitmap.FromStream(New MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(ilp.URL))), Bitmap)
            SetImage(ilp.Target, tImage)
        End Using

    End Sub

    Friend Sub SetImage(target As PictureBox, bmp As Bitmap)
        If target.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New SetImageCallback(AddressOf SetImage)
            Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {target, bmp})
        Else
            target.Image = bmp
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim src1 As New Uri("file:///C:/temp/hit.png")
        LoadImageFromUrl(PictureBox1, src1)

    End Sub

End Class
```

To check it works, I tested it with two pictureboxes and loaded, in turn, a slow-to-download image and a fast-to-download image. The fast one appeared first despite being started second.